# Excel - value of the last changed cell in row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I hope someone can help, I have a number of cells in a row which is filled automatically by another application, I need to read the last changed value in that row into one cell. I know I can create some VBA for is has to be done by formula for my application to work

So for example A1, A2 & A3 will change dynamically, B1 will have to equal the value of the cell that last changed.

Comment: when you say last changed, would the row update out of order? For instance A3 might not be "last filled"?

Answer (score 0):

With VBA, it's very easy. You can use Worksheet_Change to check for changes in a specific range(For example "A1:C10").

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1:C10")) Is Nothing Then 
    Sheet("NameOfYourSheet").Range("B1").Value = Target.value

End Sub
```

In this example the range A1 to C10 will be observed and if something changes inside this range, than the value of the cell B1 will be the value of the last changed cell.

But with just using a formula it's very hard/ nearly impossible to find the last value who has changed.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the reply, Unfortunately I cant use VBA due to the application im using. It will have to be done using Excel formula :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I've overread the "formula" part. Sorry, that's the only way I know to do, what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Chris, managed to finally figure out how my application will be using excel as a datasource and needs the one cell to trigger some events. Based on 3 input fields i used and index match to work out what the value should be =INDEX(V2:V4,MATCH(V1,U2:U4,0)

Comment: Nice. I would recommend you to answer your question and then accept your answer. Because Other people may have the same problem.